# RVM: how to get path to installed gems for init scripts

Tags: rvm

Using rvm, I have installed a few gems that come with executable scripts, such as [god](http://godrb.com).

```
$ gem install god
$ which god 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/god
```

I'd like to invoke god from an `/etc/init.d` script, but would prefer not to hard code the path. Is there a way to query rvm for the path to the "default" ruby gems directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to [generate a wrapper script](https://rvm.io/integration/init-d/).

```
$ rvm wrapper 1.9.3-p362 bootup god
$ ls -l /usr/local/rvm/bin/bootup_god 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root rvm 43 Jan 25 13:38 /usr/local/rvm/bin/bootup_god -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p362/god*
```